# Re-open turtle after turtle.bye()

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have some code as follows:

```
# My code here

turtle.bye()
```

After that, is there any way I can reopen the turtle window.
I know you can do `turtle.clearscreen()` but that does not close the turtle window.

I will accept any answer which allows me to close the turtle graphics window and then reopen it without opening and running another python program to do this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I've seen situations where the approach of @LukeTimmons worked but not always reliably and not in every situation.  Give this solution a try:

```
import time
import turtle

turtle.dot(200, 'green')

time.sleep(2)

turtle.bye()

# These two lines (indirectly) resurrect turtle environment after turtle.bye()
turtle.Turtle._screen = None  # force recreation of singleton Screen object
turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True  # only set upon TurtleScreen() definition

turtle.dot(200, 'red')

turtle.mainloop()
```

It resets two flags that keep turtle from starting up again.  It may be safer to create your own turtle after restart rather than use the default turtle which may point back to the departed environment.

Answer (score 1):

There may be other ways but this is the only way I know.

```
from turtle import *

def turtle1():
    #Your code here

turtle1()

turtle.bye()

turtle1()
```

This should re-run your code without re-typing it.

Comment: Also, `turtle.bye()` should simply be `bye()` based on your `import *`.

Comment: It might be the version of python you are using.